# How to launch tests on APK from CI?

Tags: android, gradle, android-uiautomator

I have a CI server to build APK from GIT and it is working well.

I need to launch automatic tests (UI Automator) on builds produced by CI server. To achieve it I:

1. setup CI server to build APK with tests by command `gradlew assembleDebug`. I also tried to build it with `gradlew assembleDebug -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=/path/to/keystore.jks -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=password1 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=myapp -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=password2`
2. Trying to launch it with command `adb.exe shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e package com.mysite.myapp com.mysite.myapp.test/com.mysite.myapp.runner.MyCustomTestsRunner`

And no luck. I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.mysite.myapp.test/com.mysite.myapp.runner.MyCustomTestsRunner} from pid=4922, uid=4922 not allowed be
cause package com.mysite.myapp.test does not have a signature matching the target com.mysite.myapp
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startInstrumentation(IActivityManager.java:5441)
        at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:512)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:196)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:56)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:338)
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.mysite.myapp.test/com.mysite.myapp.runner.MyCustomTestsRunner} from pid=4922, uid=4922 not allowed b
ecause package com.mysite.myapp.test does not have a signature matching the target com.mysite.myapp
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerService.java:15744)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2350)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2741)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

How does it works? I guess the APK already contains tests inside and there is no need to install some additional code... Or I have to build tests on CI too? How to launch tests on local computer using APK from CI?

Comment: Could you post your app `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably having a signing issue with the debug variant of your app since the instrumented tests use the debug variant by default. Only way to tell is to check the `build.gradle` file of your app module and see what `signingConfigs` are applied.

My suggestion is to try the following. Since eventually the CI is just running a command script, test this on your development machine and see if it succeeds:

1. Open a command terminal and run the following commands which will build your application and the Android instrumented tests in debug variant and then install them both to a connected Android device:

   - `gradlew clean`
   - `gradlew assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest installDebug installDebugAndroidTest`
2. Launch the instrumented test cases:

   - `adb.exe shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e package com.mysite.myapp com.mysite.myapp.test/com.mysite.myapp.runner.MyCustomTestsRunner`

If the exception `java.lang.SecurityException` is still appearing, then this should indicate more that something with signing of the APK is incorrect.